# Concating 3 "functions" instead of saving each apart

Tags: python, for-loop, save

I am trying to concatenate between 3 related parts, instead of saving each part in a new folder and working on that folder:

### Part I

#Removing numbers from data, gettings those occured most e.g: if "DGM1" occurred the most and he was paired with "TGM"."YTS6", "ITT7" but weren't paired with "GTX1" -- > "DGM1 and "GTX1" will be saved".

```
def write_results(file_name):
    """write the results to output files"""
    file=open(file_name,'a')
    str1=','.join(most)+'\n'
    file.write(str1)
    file.close()
os.chdir(r'xxxxxxxx')
dir = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
for files in dir:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)
    else:
        break
    for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt*')):
        with open(file_name) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines() # string to list
            lines = [element for item in lines for element in item.split(',')] # splitting list
            lines = [x for x in lines if "." not in x] # removing numbers
            n = 2 # 2 lists inside list of lists
            lines = [lines[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lines), n)] # groups of 2
            while len(lines) > 0:
                most = multimode(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist)
                file_save = os.path.join(dir ,file_name[4:] + '.txt')
                write_results(file_save)
                connected = [bin for bin in lines for a in most if a in bin]
        for i, k in connected:
            lines = [bin for bin in lines if (i not in bin ) or (k not in bin)]
```

### Part II

#Most of the files having the same name in first 6 letters: "GTXGTX1 -0.01.txt", GTXGTX1 - 0.001.txt" and so on -- > join them into one.

```
path = Path(xxxx, 'xxxxx')
os.chdir(path)
all_files = os.listdir(path)
txt_files = [i for i in all_files if i[-4:] == '.txt']
prefixes = [i[:6] for i in txt_files]
prefixes = list(set(prefixes))
for group in prefixes:
    group_txt_files = [i for i in txt_files if i[:6] == group]
    new_path = Path(path, 'xxxx', group + '.txt')
    if len(group) > 0:
        with open(new_path , 'w') as outfile:
            for file_name in group_txt_files:
                with open(file_name) as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read())
```

What I tried for this part (but it gone for wrong loop:

```
for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt*')):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()  # string to list
        lines = [element for item in lines for element in item.split(',')]  # splitting list
        lines = [x for x in lines if "." not in x]  # removing numbers
        n = 2  # 2 lists inside list of lists
        lines = [lines[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lines), n)]  # groups of 2
        while len(lines) > 0:
            most = multimode(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist)
            for in_file in path:
                txt_files = [i for i in path if i[-4:] == '.txt']
                prefixes = [i[:6] for i in txt_files]
                prefixes = list(set(prefixes))
                for group in prefixes:
                    group_txt_files = [i for i in txt_files if i[:6] == group]
                    file_save = os.path.join(in_dir, group + '.txt')
                    write_results_t(file_save)
            connected = [bin for bin in lines for a in most if a in bin]
            for i, k in connected:
                lines = [bin for bin in lines if (i not in bin) or (k not in bin)]
```

### Part III

#Getting frequency, e.g: "GTX1" appeard 5 times, "WAS",11 -- > type in [('WAS', 11), ('GTX1', 5)]

```
calc = r'xxxxxxx'
new_dir = r'xxxxxxx'
for files in calc:
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.mkdir(new_dir)
    else:
        break
    os.chdir(calc)
    for files in glob.glob(os.path.join('*.txt*')):
        #print(files) # iterating over xxxx if prints
        with open(files) as f:
            content = (item for line in f for item in line.replace('\n', '').split(','))
            list = Counter(bin for bin in content).most_common()
            with open(new_dir + files, "w") as output:
                output.write(str(list))
```

The first data appeared inside 600+ txt files, 2 string pairs , third is a number and it's removed after first part --> first possible line: GTX1,GBA,0.000341

### Editing:

Code running on a folder containing files such as: "AV8GF00_0.01" , "AV8FG00_0.0001", "AV8FG00_0.00001", "AVB0090_0.001" and etc..
Each file contains 2 pairs of strings and a value: "JAK2,LONP1,3.941044066754e-10",
"JAK2,TCF4,8.7493248674563e-39",
"LMF1,STAT6,3.685937473992248e-18" etc..

After running part 1, in the following example I should get "JAK2" and "LMF1", part 2 is joining the files with same name (except the numbers) so "AV8FG00" files will be added together without the numbers, and the strings inside as well:

"MCM8
FOXP3
KRT16
GTX1
LIPT1
WAS
SOX11,PDGFRB,ABCB4,SOX2
B9D1"

Part 3, will calculate each frequency, in this case it's 1: [('MCM8', 1), ('FOXP3', 1)]...

Answer (score 1):

```py
import contextlib
import os
from pathlib import Path
from statistics import multimode
from collections import Counter


# Go to dir and then return back
@contextlib.contextmanager
def cd(path):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(cwd)


def remove_numbers(strings):
    return [s for s in strings if '.' not in s]


def get_file_prefix(file_name):
    return file_name[:6]


def get_file_most_frequent_strings(file_name):
    result = []
    with open(file_name) as fin:
        for line in fin.read().splitlines():
            strings = line.split(',')
            strings = remove_numbers(strings)
            strings = multimode(strings)
            result += strings
    return result


def calculate_frequency(strings):
    return Counter(strings).most_common()


def get_string_frequency_by_file_prefix():
    prefix_strings = {}
    for file_name in os.listdir('.'):
        prefix = get_file_prefix(file_name)
        prefix_strings.setdefault(prefix, [])
        prefix_strings[prefix] += get_file_most_frequent_strings(file_name)

    prefix_string_frequency = {}
    for prefix, strings in prefix_strings.items():
        prefix_string_frequency[prefix] = calculate_frequency(strings)
    return prefix_string_frequency


source_dir = 'directory_to_parse_files_from'
result_dir = 'directory_to_write_results'


with cd(source_dir):
    prefix_string_frequency = get_string_frequency_by_file_prefix()

Path(result_dir).mkdir(exist_ok=True)  # Make dir if it doesn't exist

with cd(result_dir):
    for prefix, strings in prefix_string_frequency.items():
        with open(prefix + '.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(str(strings))
```

Comment: I edited, and no, if the file exists, I do not need to run the code again, it can work without the break part, I understand but that's no the issue. I want to run one code on one folder instead of creating 3 folders, only create one.

Comment: I implemented the issue in a way how I understood from your description.

Comment: Not the same thing I needed, but you gave me an idea, thanks